# Ionic Angular Js making 2 requests to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Using Ionic framework 1,

Making request using `$http.post();` but, in the console.. two requests are getting generated.

the first request doesn't contain the `POST` parameters and is blank , while the second request contains the `POST` parameters as passed to  `$http.post()` method.

What could be the possible reason ? 
**May be it's checking if already cached resource is updated or not by making a blank request to the server, before making a request to load data**.

But, I have not enabled any caching or anything. Everything is default.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first request is the `Request Method: OPTIONS` request. It checks whether or not the actual request is safe to send. It is also called 'preflighted request'

Comment: Thanks ! I was totally unaware of 'preflighted requests'  .